# Changing a Custom Adapter for List<String>

Tags: java, android, json

I currently have an adapter class called TaskListAdapter, that currently only takes care of one textView, but later will be changed to hold 2 textViews and 2 imageViews, the code is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TaskListItem> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
TaskListItem data[] = null;

public TaskListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, TaskListItem[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    TaskListHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new TaskListHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtDashCol1Name);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (TaskListHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    TaskListItem list_item = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(list_item.title);

    return row;
}

static class TaskListHolder
{
    TextView txtTitle;
}
```

}

It uses the TaskListItem class, which is this:

```
public class TaskListItem {
    public String title;
    public TaskListItem() {
        super();
    }

    public TaskListItem(String title) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

Now, in my main class that handles the JSON Query, It currently populates a List. I am extremely new to Java and Android developing, so please try to explain all answers! This is the section where I get a response from a URL, then parse the response.

```
//It first gets the response from the http request.
            String response = new RequestTask(this).execute(MY_URL).get();
            //And then parses the JSONObject that is returned
            JSONObject results = new JSONObject(response);
            recordList = results.getJSONArray("records");
            int length = recordList.length();

            //Below, the text item at the top of the list which indicates the number of tasks total, is populated.
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTotalListItems)).setText("Tasks (" + length + ")");

            //Then it loops around each entry in the JSONObject and adds anything with the label 'title' into an array
            List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);
            for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject item = recordList.getJSONObject(i);
                listContents.add(item.getString("title"));
            }

            myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltPageTwoList);
            myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TaskList.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtTitle, listContents));
```

This is surrounded by a try/catch clause and all seems to work normally if I use the standard setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter... thing. What I want to be able to do is have a custom adapter for things like alternate list colors, populating multiple textViews and imageViews. Any ideas guys? The first thing I tried was this:

```
TaskListAdapter task = new TaskListAdapter(this, R.layout.task_list_layout, listContents);
```

But it throws up the error:

```
The constructor TaskListAdapter(TaskList, int, List<String>) is undefined
```

So... any help? Thanks in advance! As I said before... I am extremely new to this field so try not to be too harsh!

Comment: listContents is List of String, not array of TaskListItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A List isn't the same thing as an array of objects. An array is a more basic type and can't be used interchangbly with a list. You weren't having any problem earlier because with an ArrayAdapter, there are multiple constructors, one of which is overloaded to use a List of objects.

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

In the class you defined, you only define a constructor that takes in a array of objects, and constructors are not inherited in Java, although you can still access them with a super() call.

To fix your problem, simply change your constructor to

```
TaskListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<TaskListItem> objects)
```

and change the references to reflect you're using an List. Namely:

```
List<TaskListItem> data = new ArrayList <TaskListItem> ();
...
TaskListItem task_item = data.get(position);
```

If you're confused about List vs array, ArrayList vs List, or inheritance, I think those are too broad for the scope of the question and I recommend going through some basic java tutorials. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

EDIT:
So in the class where you parse the JSON, make the add call into

```
add(new TaskListItem(item.getString("title"))
```

and also, do what I originally intended which is in the `Adapter` class, change all your references to the array into references to the list.

It slipped my mind that you were earlier using a list of String in the class where you parse the json and that you would change that list.

A quick note is by parameterizing a `List` you tell the Java compiler you're only going to be putting objects of a certain type in there. You parameterized the list with the type `TaskListItem` so it would not longer accept type String. What I told you to do changes your add call so it creates a new TaskListItem for each String and adds that, instead of attempting to add the plain String. If you're still having problems after this, post your full code and I'll try and help more.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer.

I have edited it appropriately however now the section where I parse the JSON and populate the list with .add() is throwing up an error. It says:

"The method add(TaskListItem) in the type List<TaskListItem> is not applicable for the arguments (String)" 

Any ideas??

Comment: Edited to reflect what was missing.